# How to detect onMoveStart and onMoveStop on dijit/form/HorizontalSlider?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I am using dojo 1.10.4, I need to detect events `onMouseStart` and `onMouseStop` on the "slider element inside" inside my `dijit/form/HorizontalSlider`.

At the moment I am trying to detect is on  object `_movable` (it is an `dojo/dnd/Moveable`) but with no success, getting error:

```
Moveable.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

- How to listen to `onMouseStart` and `onMouseStop` on HorizontalSlider?
- Alternatively do you know nay better way to detect when user **starts** and **ends** sliding.

Live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/9uo1doan/

```
require([
  "dojo/dom",
  "dijit/form/HorizontalSlider",
  "dijit/form/TextBox",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(dom, HorizontalSlider, TextBox) {
  var slider = new HorizontalSlider({
    name: "slider",
    value: 5,
    minimum: -10,
    maximum: 10,
    intermediateChanges: true,
    style: "width:300px;",
    onChange: function(value) {
      dom.byId("sliderValue").value = value;
    }
  }, "slider");

  slider._movable.onMoveStart(function(event) {
    console.log('onMoveStart');
  });
  slider._movable.onMoveStop(function(event) {
    console.log('onMoveStop');
  });
  slider._movable.onFirstMove(function(event) {
    console.log('onFirstMove');
  });
  slider._movable.onMove(function(event) {
    console.log('onMove');
  });
  slider._movable.onMoving(function(event) {
    console.log('onMoving');
  });
  slider._movable.onMoved(function(event) {
    console.log('onMoved');
  });

});
```

---

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<p>
  <input type="text" id="sliderValue" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" />
```

Reference: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dnd/Moveable.html

---

I have also tried with no sucess:

```
  on(slider._movable, 'moveStart', function(e){});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue using `dojo/aspect`.

Basically the solutions I found is to running my function after method `onMoveStart` is executed on `dojo/dnd/Moveable` .

I am still interested in understanding why a more traditional approach with an event listener did not work out.

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8z6sm14j/

```
require([
  "dojo/dom",
  "dojo/on",
  "dojo/aspect",
  "dijit/form/HorizontalSlider",
  "dijit/form/TextBox",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(dom, on, aspect, HorizontalSlider, TextBox) {
  debugger
  var slider = new HorizontalSlider({
    name: "slider",
    value: 5,
    minimum: -10,
    maximum: 10,
    intermediateChanges: true,
    style: "width:300px;",
    onChange: function(value) {
      dom.byId("sliderValue").value = value;
    }
  }, "slider");
    var result = document.getElementById('result');

  aspect.after(slider._movable, 'onMoveStart', function(event) {
    console.log('onMoveStart');
    result.innerHTML = 'onMoveStart';
  });

  aspect.after(slider._movable, 'onMoveStop', function(event) {
    console.log('onMoveStop');
    result.innerHTML = 'onMoveStop';
  });

});
```

---

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<input type="text" id="sliderValue" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Just for reference, I was able to came up with this solutions after looking at [this module](https://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/aikau-jsdoc/AlfDialog.js.html).